# Is there a way to ignore invalid keys with get_multi?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I would like to have `get_multi` return `None` for keys with invalid ids.

```
class Entity(ndb.Model):
    pass

ids = [0, 1]
rows = ndb.get_multi([Key(Entity, id) for id in ids])
```

Actual result

`BadRequestError('missing key id/name')`

Desired result

`[None, <Entity with id 1>]`

The reason I'm not calling `filter` on `ids` is that I want indices in `ids` to correspond to indices in `rows`.

Comment: You will only get a badrequest error if the key is invalid, not missing.  How are you going to ensure the indices match unless you allocate ids

Comment: If they're missing (`None`), I get a null pointer, which is still a problem. They always match when using `get_multi` and valid keys.

Comment: If you didn't get None you could not tell which keys did not return a value.

Comment: So why not just `rows = [row for i in ndb.get_multi([Key(Entity, id) for id in ids]) if i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `get_multi` is just a helper function, my best solution so far is to copy the code and only run the query if `id > 0`.

```
ids = [0, 1]
futures = [Key(Entity, id).get_async() if id > 0 else None for id in ids]
rows = [future.get_result() if future else None for future in futures]
```